# Should we have a Cook's distance tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

We have [tens of questions mentioning Cook's distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cook%27s%20distance). Should we have a tag for them?

Comment: More relevant search query: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22cook%27s+distance%22+is%3Aquestion

Comment: +1. See here: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3101 for some useful advice about creating new tags.

Comment: We already seem to have a tag for leverage (but not one for influence). Do we need to have separate ones for all of these concepts? This is a genuine question to which I have no answer.

Comment: @mdewey What is "leverage" (the [leverage] tag has no wiki excerpt), and how is it related to Cook's distance?

Comment: @amoeba as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics). I view Cook as a compromise between leverage and residual in my simplistic way. If there is a consensus about these concepts I will write the wiki for leverage unless someone gets there first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment we have a number of possibly relevant tags

1. [leverage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leverage) which has 27 entries but no wiki excerpt
2. [diagnostic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagnostic) which has 162 entries a wiki excerpt but no extended wiki
3. [regression-diagnostic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression-diagnostic) which is a synonym of [diagnostic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagnostic)
4. [schoenfeld-residuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schoenfeld-residuals) which has 10 entries and no wiki excerpt

As @Pere remarks we have no tag for Cook's distance.

There are well used tags for [residuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/residuals) and [residual-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/residual-analysis).

The simplest solution would be to create the tag for Cook's distance, write wikis for it and leverage and in them suggest the possibility of using [diagnostic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagnostic) if more than one diagnostic is being considered.

EDIT added 1 March 2017

We now have a tag [cooks-distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooks-distance) with wiki and excerpt and also wiki and excerpt for [leverage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leverage). I will tag the ones picked up in the search noted in comments.

Further edit 6 March

I have now gone through all the ones thrown up by @Amoeba's search mentioned in comments and tagged most of them. Some, about one quarter, were not really about Cook, they just mentioned it so I have left them un-tagged.

Comment: And here is my tag synonym proposal for residual-analysis -> residuals: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/4652/28666.